# Why can't I use the build arg again after FROM in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm using Docker `18.05.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu` and I'd like to pass a build argument to the FROM as well as other lines in my Dockerfile. You would expect the below to work:

```
ARG FROM_IMAGE=ubuntu:bionic
FROM $FROM_IMAGE

COPY sources_list/$FROM_IMAGE /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It works for the second line (`FROM`), but it behaves like it is unset in the `COPY` line:

> Step 1/3 : ARG FROM_IMAGE=ubuntu:bionic
>   Step 2/3 : FROM $FROM_IMAGE
>    ---> 8626492fecd3
>   [...]
>   Step 3/3 : COPY sources_list/${SOURCES_LIST_FILE} /etc/apt/sources.list
>   failed to copy files: failed to copy directory: mkdir
>   /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0536b4e280ddca2fec18db9d79fa625a8be86efdbaaea5b3dbbefcdaaab3f669/merged/etc/apt/sources.list:
>   not a directory

If add another, separate build arg, it works for the same `COPY` line:

```
ARG FROM_IMAGE=ubuntu:bionic
FROM $FROM_IMAGE

ARG SOURCES_LIST_FILE
COPY sources_list/${SOURCES_LIST_FILE} /etc/apt/sources.list
```

> Step 4/4 : COPY sources_list/${SOURCES_LIST_FILE} /etc/apt/sources.list
>    ---> 7f974fffe929

Why can't I use the `FROM_IMAGE` build arg twice, on and after a `FROM` line? I fail to find any documented restriction of this sort.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why can't I use the FROM_IMAGE build arg twice, on and after a FROM line?

There is a real difference depending on where you put ARG related to FROM line:

- any ARG before the first FROM can be used in any FROM line
- any ARG within a build stage (after a FROM) can be used in that build stage

This is related to build stages mechanics and some reference of actual behavior can be found here: https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/333, and a discussion on why documentation and build mechanics is a bit confusing on ARG usage is here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34129

Comment: Ah, yes. It's explained here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact and I should just basically repeat the ARG statement after the FROM line.