# docker pass build arg to the shell script which needs to be run during the docker building

Tags: docker

The problem is i cannot get the docker build arg value in the shell script while running the docker build.

My docker build command:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --no-cache --progress=plain \
  -t test \
  --build-arg WHL_PATH=/fake/path \
  .
```

Dockerfile

```
ARG WHL_PATH

FROM python:3.8.8

COPY test.sh .

RUN ./test.sh $WHL_PATH
```

and in the `test.sh` the `"$1"` is empty...., if in the `Dockerfile` i put some constant value then i will be able to see that value in the `$1`, but with docker build arg or set the build arg as ENV VAR are always empty...

Where am i doing wrong, how should i achieve this?

```
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
```

Answer (score 1):

Build args are scoped. Before the first FROM step they only apply to the FROM steps to adjust the image you use. Within each stage, an ARG step applies to the remaining steps within that stage. So the fix is to reorder your steps:

```
FROM python:3.8.8

COPY test.sh .

ARG WHL_PATH

RUN ./test.sh $WHL_PATH
```

Comment: yup, you are right, i really should come here to ask earlier...

Answer (score 1):

Oops, i never realised  the position of the `ARG` instruction matters, basically:

- any ARG before the first FROM can be used in any FROM line
- any ARG within a build stage (after a FROM) can be used in that build stage

After i moved the `ARG WHL_PATH` after the line `FROM xxx` it works perfectly, hope this can save some of your time in the future.

And i was inspired by this answer actually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50292255/7658313

Comment: WOW! This isn't at all confusing!  In one dockerfile, the ARG must appear after the FROM statement.  While in a different dockerfile, several ARG statements appear before the FROM statement and behave as global variables (addt'l ARG statements duplicate the previous declaration as if to "import" the variable?).  No idea why this is working.